# Safari browser crashes on redirect window.location

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile-safari

I am using this code to open application if its installed else will ask to install.

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
        var end = (new Date()).valueOf();
        if (end - start < 1000) { 
            window.setTimeout(function () {
                window.location = pageurl;//will be redirected to webpage crash is happening here
            }, 5);
            window.location = storeurl;
        } else {
            window.location = pageurl;
        }
    }, 5);
    window.location = appicationurl;// will defaultly open application
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `window.open(pageurl);`

```
 window.setTimeout(function () {
            var end = (new Date()).valueOf();
            if (end - start < 1000) { 
                window.setTimeout(function () {
                    window.open(pageurl);//will be redirected to webpage crash is happening here
                }, 5);
                window.location = storeurl;
            } else {
                window.location = pageurl;
            }
        }, 5);
        window.location = appicationurl;// will defaultly open application
```

Answer (score 0):

use `window.location.href`

```
window.setTimeout(function () { 
                         window.location.href = "http://sample.com"; 
                    }, 5000);
```

Comment: I used your code but that one also leads to the crash.

Comment: but, code working on my safari 5.1.7 (windows). any errors are shown in console?

Comment: the problem is in iPhone Safari browser.

Comment: try this one `document.location.replace("https://google.com");` but won't  able to go back page.

Comment: document.location.replace also crashing.